# Python: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, string, list

Hi am trying to print a list of string in python but still its showing me this error.
"list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

code:

```
Features ['entity_number',
 'type',
 'programs',
 'name',
 'title',
 'addresses']
```

So in here i just want to display the data under 'name'.

can some one help me to resolve this problem..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B42jk.png)

Comment: It looks like you actually want to use dictionaries, not lists

Comment: Error is clear, you want `Features[Features.index('name')]` so that you use the ordinal index pos to return the index for that entry

Comment: print Features [0]

Comment: share your code. or describe your question more clearly

Comment: @EdChum What would be the point in that? It's O(n) worse case and it would just `return` the input name? Probably they actually have a `dict` and their "data under name" are the values

Comment: @Chris_Rands true, but as the OP hasn't stated their real problem I can only answer the immediate problem

Comment: @EdChum Agreed, sorry I wasn't trying to attack you. Anyway it's a xy problem at best and just completely unclear otherwise, and should be closed IMO

Comment: @Chris_Rands I didn't treat it as a attack, so no worries. I fired a quick comment without thinking what the OP really intends, it's a poor question because the error is pretty clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it looks like you are looking for a dictionary`{}` and not a list`[]`. A dictionary has the added benefit of allowing for what is known as a 'key: value' pairs. If you know your key, you can get your value!

```
Features = {
       'entity_number': 'some number',
       'type': 'some type',
       'programs': 'some program',
       'name': 'some name',
       'title': 'some title',
       'addresses': 'some address'
       }
```

To find a specific value from a key, you can do the following:

```
for key, value in Features.items():
    if key is 'name': #'name' is the key we wish to get the value from
        print(value) # print its value
```

this will give you the output:

`some name`

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally got the answer what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
features= pd.Dataframe({
'entity_number': list1,
 'type': list2, 
 'programs': list3,
 'name': list4
 'title': list5
 'addresses': list6
})
```